# Generic dependency injection and DataContext Injection issue error CS0119

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build my own implementation of IdentityPackage. In my project I have a class AddIdenitityServices. When trying to inject the class into the service collection I get the error CS0119. I am still learning about generics so when I searched up the error it did not make much sense to me.

Here is my injection code.

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices<TUser,TDbContext>
      (this IServiceCollection services,
       IdentityDbOptions options
      ) where TDbContext : IdentityDbContext<TUser> where TUser : IdentityDbUser 
    {
      services.AddScoped<IIdentityServiceManager<TUser>, IdentityServicesManager<TUser,TDbContext>();
      return services;
    }
```

Here is my Service manager code

```
public class IdentityServicesManager<TUser, TDbContext>
   where TDbContext : IdentityDbContext<TUser> where TUser : IdentityDbUser,
    IIdentityServiceManager<TUser>
  {
    private readonly TDbContext _context;

    public IdentityServicesManager(TDbContext context)
    {
      _context = context ?? throw new NullReferenceException($"{nameof(context)} was null");
    }
  }
```

and finally my IdentityDbContext

```
  public class IdentityDbContext<TUser>: DbContext where TUser : IdentityDbUser
  {
    public IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
      
    }

    public DbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }

  }
```

I did try making the Interface also contain the TDbContext. But it still failed. It requires the TUser due to a function requiring it.

I dd also try reading though [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0119?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0119)) on the issue but I am still not sure exactly what the issue will be

Comment: Your `services.AddScoped` line is missing a `>`, possibly just before the `()`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward, my bad I forgot to add it back after tried something else. Unfortunately that is not the issue here

Comment: If that's genuinely not the problem then please edit your question to include the missing `>`. However, while I can reproduce the CS0119 error message with that `>` missing, I get a different error (CS0311) if I include the missing `>`. Do you? If so, edit your question to include the details of that error. Also, if that gets rid of the CS0119 error for you, please remove any mentions of this error from your question.